# Java Neo4J out of memory

Tags: java, memory, neo4j

This is a bit like this: [Neo4j OutOfMemory problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927329/neo4j-outofmemory-problem)

But it's outdated and apparently so are the solutions as far as I can tell.

So I'm trying to insert around 100K nodes with 5.5M relations (I actually cut down my data set so it's now more like <100K nodes with 2.8M relations).

After a while, it runs out of memory and I get an exception like so:

```
Exception in thread "GC-Monitor" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.StringLogger$ActualStringLogger.logMessage(StringLogger.java:276)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.cache.MeasureDoNothing.run(MeasureDoNothing.java:85)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.LinkedList.addBefore(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList.add(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.IdGeneratorImpl.freeId(IdGeneratorImpl.java:291)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.freeId(CommonAbstractStore.java:382)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.WriteTransaction.doRollback(WriteTransaction.java:315)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaTransaction.rollback(XaTransaction.java:278)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceManager.rollback(XaResourceManager.java:518)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceHelpImpl.rollback(XaResourceHelpImpl.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TransactionImpl.doRollback(TransactionImpl.java:558)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.rollback(TxManager.java:610)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:129)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.finish(TopLevelTransaction.java:119)
    at sqlToGraph.SqlToGraph.main(SqlToGraph.java:81)
```

I've tried passing -Xmx1500m to java, which is about the limit of what I can pass because before it complains about not being able to allocate the heap space. It lasts significantly longer, but still doesn't finish.

Here is the (slightly edited) code:

```
/* Postgres query and setup stuff cut */
Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
try {
    while (rs.next()) {
        user_lo = rs.getInt(1);
        user_hi = rs.getInt(2);
        n_lo = getOrCreate(user_lo, graphDb);
        n_lo.setProperty("user_id", user_lo);
        n_lo.setProperty("total", rs.getInt(3));
        n_hi = getOrCreate(user_hi, graphDb);
        n_hi.setProperty("user_id", user_hi);
        n_hi.setProperty("total", rs.getInt(4));
        relationship = n_lo.createRelationshipTo(n_hi, RelTypes.PLAYED_WITH);
        relationship.setProperty("mean_percent", rs.getDouble(5));
    }
    tx.success();
} finally {
    tx.finish();
}
graphDb.shutdown();
```

Comment: If you obtain a 64 bit system and JVM, you could try setting heap larger if you think your algorithm can't be improved to use less memory.

Comment: How often are you committing the transactions? May we see your code?

Comment: Not very often? Like, once? Is that my problem? Added the code.

Comment: Realising I had this stuff installed already, I tried this and set the heap to a nice 8gb. It completely stalled my computer overnight and I had to reset :( Oh, I also tried stuff lower than this, like 6gb, but ran out of heap pretty quickly.

Comment: That is indeed the problem. Transaction data is held in memory until committed. Commit (restart the transaction) every ten thousand or so.

Comment: Thanks for the code pasted here, restarting the transaction now and then, every couple of thousands inserts or so, will solve the problem.

Comment: Can I just do this by keeping a counter and randomly callling commit every x iterations or is there more to it than this? Also go ahead and write this up as a proper answer so I can thingy it if you like (if it works)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding another answer here. So given the code the problem is that you never commit your transaction. Transaction data is kept in memory until committed so all your created nodes and relationships will just sit in memory awaiting a commit and that's why you eventually get OOM.

I'd propose this code change:

```
/* Postgres query and setup stuff cut */
Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
try {
    for (int i = 0; rs.next(); i++) {
        user_lo = rs.getInt(1);
        user_hi = rs.getInt(2);
        n_lo = getOrCreate(user_lo, graphDb);
        n_lo.setProperty("user_id", user_lo);
        n_lo.setProperty("total", rs.getInt(3));
        n_hi = getOrCreate(user_hi, graphDb);
        n_hi.setProperty("user_id", user_hi);
        n_hi.setProperty("total", rs.getInt(4));
        relationship = n_lo.createRelationshipTo(n_hi, RelTypes.PLAYED_WITH);
        relationship.setProperty("mean_percent", rs.getDouble(5));

        // Commit every now and then to free memory.
        if ( i > 0 && i % 10000 == 0 ) {
            tx.success();
            tx.finish();
            tx = graphDb.beginTx();
        }
    }
    tx.success();
} finally {
    tx.finish();
}
graphDb.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

If splitting up the transaction is not feasible for you as you rely on the atomicity guarantee of a single  transaction, another option might be to simplify the data model, e.g. reduce the number of properties added to nodes/relationships.

In our case we could fix an OOM issue by omitting properties that held default values or zeros.