# Long running Neo4j transactions cause OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, neo4j

I am using an embedded Neo4j 2.1.2 database and experience memory troubles when creating large number of relations or nodes in a single transaction that is committed in smaller batch sizes. Should/must I avoid using a single long running transaction? I would have expected the memory usage to grow with the commit batch size instead.

You can reproduce the error with this simple code:

```
try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
    for (int idx=1; idx<=amount; idx++) {
        if (idx % 10000 == 0) {
            tx.success();
        }
        Node n = db.createNode();
    }
    tx.success();
}
```

I am getting an OutOfMemoryError after 580.000 nodes have been inserted with a heap size of 512MB. The VM flags used are: `-server -Xmx512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`

If I modify the code to use new transactions for each batch it is working fine and very quick:

```
Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
try {
    for (int idx=1; idx<=amount; idx++) {
        if (idx % 10000 == 0) {
            tx.success();
            tx.close();
            tx = db.beginTx();
        }
        Node n = db.createNode();
    }
    tx.success();

} finally {
    tx.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that the references to your Nodes are kept on the heap as they are located in a transaction and must be kept for rollback purposes hence you run out of memory after 580 000 nodes. If you run the same code in small batch sizes this should fix your problem as long as the batch size does not exceed 580 000.

As for your second question: java heap memory is allocated but cannot be increased dynamically  when your program needs more

You need to trigger void close() otherwise it does not release the resources.

http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.html#close()
Commits or marks this transaction for rollback, depending on whether success() or failure() has been previously invoked.

I think this question is duplicate by the way:

[Java Neo4J out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103436/java-neo4j-out-of-memory)

Comment: I should have read the Transaction docs more carefully. I expected the semantics of success() and close() to be as their JDBC Connection counterpart commit() and close(). But that was obviously wrong. Thanks!