# Neo4j out of memory error when creating large graph

Tags: java, neo4j, out-of-memory

I am using Neo4j database in java and I need to put large amount of nodes in it but I am getting out of memory  error. I managed to delay the out of memory by commiting of transaction every 1000th node like this:

```
Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
try
{   
   try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("page_links_en.ttl"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
   int n = 0;          
   for (String line = null; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
      n++;
      Node node = graphDb.createNode();
      node.setProperty("uri",line);
      if((n % 1000) == 0){                              
        tx.success();
        tx.close();                     
        tx = graphDb.beginTx()
      }
   }
}...
```

but unfortunately for me this just delayed the time when the out of memory error comes. I am sure that this problem has something to do with node creation and that there is no other memory leak in other part of app. So I want to ask for help with this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How big is the file you are reading? Could the reading cause oom? Try to comment out the graph stuff and do simple System.out in the for loop.

Comment: I actualy did this, I am sure it is not problem of reading. I spent another 2 hours on this and I managed to get rid of error, but the program is consuming 1.6 GB of RAM. Maybe I do not understand to garbage collector in java but it seems to me too much for such a simple program.

Comment: Is this stemmed from the same issue as this one regarding the Java Heap Size and Memory Mapped Buffers? I know you are not using windows, but maybe it's the same underlying problem.  Neo4j tries to maintain some sort of in-memory cache of nodes.

Comment: are you also committing after your loop? I.e. the last open transaction? You can increase the batch-size to 30-50k elements.

Comment: Thank you for you reactions, Yes I am commiting after loop and @LameCoder Do you wanted do add some link, because by some mistake it was not added

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927329/neo4j-outofmemory-problem?rq=1